# Need some help writing a custom movement

Tags: vim

I want a movement to jump to the end of a block of code. I wrote a function and I'm trying to onoremap it, but it doesn't work. Here is what I do:

```
onoremap <silent> } :set opfunc=MovementToEdgeOfBlock(1)<cr>g@
```

If I do simply:

```
nnoremap <silent> } :call MovementToEdgeOfBlock(1)<cr>
```

then the function works as intended. But I need it more as a movement for other commands. So what am I doing wrong?

Here is the function itself (I don't think that the problem is in the function, but anyway):

```
function! MovementToEdgeOfBlock(direction)
    let startLine=line(".")
    function! HowManyTabs(line)
        let i=0
        while a:line[i]==#"\t"
            let i+=1
        endwhile
        return i
    endfunction
    let startLineTabs = HowManyTabs(getline("."))
    echom startLineTabs " tabs"
    if a:direction==1
        let tabs=HowManyTabs(getline(line('.')+1))
    else
        let tabs=HowManyTabs(getline(line('.')-1))
    endif
    while tabs>startLineTabs
        if a:direction==1
            execute "normal! j"
        else
            execute "normal! k"
        endif
        let tabs=HowManyTabs(getline(line('.')))
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read `:h 'opfunc'` carefully, including `:h g@` which is referenced there? It has absolutely nothing to do with what you want to achieve. More, `g@` was never intended to work in operator-pending mode. And more, `'opfunc'` option takes a function name, not an expression like you try to pass it, and passes this function one string argument.

What you should have done is first trying to create *exactly the same mapping* for operator-pending mode as you use in normal mode. If this does not work try using `<expr>` mappings: I would have wrote your function as following:

```
" Do not redefine function each time ToEdgeOfBlock is called,
" put the definition in global scope: There is no way to have 
" a local function in any case.
" The following does exactly the same thing your one used to do (except 
" that I moved getline() here), but faster
function! s:HowManyTabs(lnr)
    return len(matchstr(getline(a:lnr), "^\t*"))
endfunction
function! s:ToEdgeOfBlock(direction)
    let startlnr=line('.')
    let startlinetabs=s:HowManyTabs(startlnr)
    let shift=(a:direction ? 1 : -1)
    let nextlnr=startlnr+shift
    while s:HowManyTabs(nextlnr)>startlinetabs && 1<=nextlnr && nextlnr<=line('$')
        let nextlnr+=shift
    endwhile
    return nextlnr.'gg'
endfunction
noremap <expr> } <SID>ToEdgeOfBlock(1)
```

My version also allows you to undo the jump using `<C-o>`.